# javax.print.PrintException: Printer is not accepting job

Tags: java, printing

I am getting the "`javax.print.PrintException: Printer is not accepting job."`, when I try to execute

```
printService.createPrintJob().print(
                    new SimpleDoc(this,
                            DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE,
                            docAttributeSet),
                    printRequestAttributeSet);
```

I am seeing this problem happening for one machine printing to the printer but the other machine is able to print to the same printer using the same API call. I was looking at bug report from Oracle Sun explaining similar problem which is pasted below.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6525150

But none of the workarounds mentioned there is fixing the problem for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing and adding the printer fixes the problem as mentioned in the bug as a workaround. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**printerName=printerName.replaceAll("#", "\\");**

don't use the default printer and if the printer is default one then replace '#' with '//'. Due to window system I got this exception, I have replaced my printer name by using the above code and my problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

While this won't resolve the reported issue (where one printer works and the other fails), this error can be reported if the printer becomes unavailable due to a systemic issue, such as if the printer runs out of toner.  In this event, changing the toner should solve it.