# javax.print.PrintException: Printer is not accepting job. On UNIX

Tags: java, printing, aix

We have a Java application installed on WebSphere 8.5 on IBM AIX 6.1. We need to print some documents using this application.

Currently we are getting this error:

```
ERROR syserr - javax.print.PrintException: Printer is not accepting job.

ERROR syserr -  at sun.print.UnixPrintJob.print(UnixPrintJob.java:307)
```

Java version used is 6.

We tried to find out solution online and found this link on Stackoverflow
[javax.print.PrintException: Printer is not accepting job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547411/javax-print-printexception-printer-is-not-accepting-job)

Performed the same steps. But it did not help.

We got this info also -

https://community.oracle.com/message/5449533

But since this solution was provided considering Windows machine, It did not work for us.

After looking at the source code for UnixPrintJob.java, we realized that below part of code is causing this error:

```
    if ((PrinterIsAcceptingJobs)(service.getAttribute(

                      PrinterIsAcceptingJobs.class)) ==

                      PrinterIsAcceptingJobs.NOT_ACCEPTING_JOBS) {

         throw new PrintException("Printer is not accepting job."); 
     }
```

source : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/print/UnixPrintJob.java

Could someone help and guide, why is this happening and what could be the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encounter similar issues and found it was related to qdaemon service which could not be access by non root user. check whether non root user can query print queues defined on the server using lpstat.

Comment: Thanks!. It helped. We were thinking that it is a Java bug.
Got some useful info from here http://aix4admins.blogspot.com/2011/08/terms-print-job-print-job-is-unit-of.html